# How to detect words in text given a set of words (almost similar) in database?

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp

Assuming we have a database containing the following words:

```
Chicken Wings
Chicken
Chicken Nuggets
Super Chicken Nuggets
```

And the text:

```
Instruction: Add super chicken nuggets and chicken wings to the salad
```

What would the logic/algorithm be if we want to extract "Super Chicken Nuggets" and "Chicken Wings" from the text, but not "Chicken" nor "Chicken Nuggets"?

I can't express the exact rule as I'm confused myself. But Since "Super Chicken Nuggets" and "Chicken Wings" are part of the text, then the two should be considered. While "Chicken" and "Chicken Nuggets" also exist in the text, but really the two are just subset to "Super Chicken Nuggets" and "Chicken Wings".

But if we have a text like `Add super chicken nuggets and chicken to the salad`, then "Super Chicken Nuggets" and "Chicken" should be extracted, but not "Chicken Nuggets".

PS: For simplicity, we may ignore the case.

Comment: You need to define what made you pick "Super Chicken Nuggets"

Comment: because it's the longest match. I just edited the post.

Comment: And I'll assume case does not matter?

Comment: Normalise the whitespace in both the candidates and input text. Sort the candidates by length, and then do a case-insensitive search for each one. First match wins. If you need anything more sophisticated than that, you will need to provide more details (and some realistic examples).

Comment: @matszwecja yes, we may ignore the case.

Comment: *Edited. Apologies, I was having trouble explaining myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` check on words sorted from the longest one.

```
text = "Instruction: Add super chicken nuggets to the salad"
textLC = text.lower()
patterns = ['Chicken Wings', 'Chicken', 'Chicken Nuggets', 'Super Chicken Nuggets']

match = None
for pattern in sorted(patterns, key=len, reverse=True):
    if pattern.lower() in text:
        match = pattern
        break
print(match)
```

Comment: Why regex and not a simple `in`?

Comment: Fair point, regex might be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

To extract "Super Chicken Nuggets" as the longest match from the text while excluding "Chicken" and "Chicken Nuggets," you can use a regular expression pattern that matches the exact phrase "Super Chicken Nuggets" and rejects any shorter matches that include the words "Chicken" or "Nuggets." Here's an example logic/algorithm:

```
import re
text = "Add super chicken nuggets to the salad"
pattern = r'\bsuper chicken nuggets\b(?<!Chicken|Nuggets)'
match = re.search(pattern, text)
if match:
# extract the matched substring
   item = match. Group()
   print(item)
else:
   print("No match found.")
```

Yes, you can use the in keyword to check if a substring is present in a larger string. However, this approach may not be as reliable as using regular expressions, especially if the substring can appear in different variations or word orders.

```
text = "Add super chicken nuggets to the salad"

# define the search phrase and reject phrases
search_phrase = "Super Chicken Nuggets"
reject_phrases = ["Chicken", "Nuggets"]

# split the text into words
words = text.split()

# initialize variables for the longest match and its length
longest_match = None
longest_match_len = 0

# iterate over the words and check for matches
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    # check if the word is the first word of the search phrase
    if word == search_phrase.split()[0]:
        # check if the remaining words form the search phrase
        match = [word]
        for j in range(1, len(search_phrase.split())):
            if i+j >= len(words):
                break
            if words[i+j] in reject_phrases:
                break
            match.append(words[i+j])
        if len(match) == len(search_phrase.split()):
            # update the longest match if the current match is longer
            if len(match) > longest_match_len:
                longest_match = " ".join(match)
                longest_match_len = len(match)

if longest_match:
    # print the longest match
    print(longest_match)
else:
    print("No match found.")
```